# Two ways data binding in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can not get the two ways data binding working in AngularJS directive.

Here is my html code from the template, used with a basic controller instantiating mymodel (an array here) :

## HTML

```
<select ng-if="mymodel" multipleselect values="mymodel">
```

## DIRECTIVE

I have a directive called multipleselect :

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope : {
    values : '='
  },
  link : function($scope, element, attrs){

    ...
    $scope.values = ["some","nice","datas"]; //Actually works, the model is changed in the controller 

    $("select").change(function(){ //This is a callback, asynchronous situation
        $scope.$apply(function () { //Using apply to notify the controller that we are changing its model
          $scope.values = ["some","amazing","datas"]; //Not working :(
        });
    });
   }
}
```

Why my model is not updated the second time I change it ?

Comment: Where did you define your `mymodel` property ? As you're using 2-way binding in your directive, there should be `mymodel` property defined on the scope of the enclosing/parent element of your `multipleselect` directive.

Comment: Ive had issues in the past with `ng-if` and such things like this, it will remove the actual element from the DOM and replace it. Don't know if it could be a similar issue. Also just so you know your change will fire for every select on the page. You should use the element object to scope your event to the directive. You should also listen to the destroy to event to remove the handler when it is remove in the `ng-if`. Could cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the answers given I think this will fit your needs without having to use a custom directive:

```
<select ng-if="mymodel" multiple ng-model="model.mymodel">
```

Your model will automatically update when the select changes as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EsQsW/2/).

The egghead.io video ["The Dot"](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) has a really good overview, as does this very popular stack overflow question: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)

Comment: @ste2425 You should always use a `.` notation when using ng-model, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vewk68xt/2/

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, yea my bad was being daft,

Comment: @ste2425 Check my response

Comment: Thank you very much it works ! I will look at the sources because for now I really don't understand why it is working

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery to watch for the change. You can write like this (also to fix your problem):

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope : {
    values : '='
  },
  link : function($scope, element, attrs){

    $scope.values = ["some","nice","datas"];

    element.on("change", function(){
         $scope.values = ["some","amazing","datas"];
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Element is a jQuery ( or jQLite if jQuery is not included before angular) object of the directive.

Comment: Why not use ng-change ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker because the directive does not specify a template. You would have to manually compile the html to add the bindings for `ng-change`.

Comment: It's a <select> so why not just bind the array to the ng-model, no need for a ng-change

Comment: @MartijnWelker, The author wants to use directive to watch for the change in the directive so using that.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal which to me looks like it is because he doesn't fully understand Angular, therefore I've added an Angular example.

Comment: @MartijnWelker I remove some code to be fully understandable, it is not a simple select, in my directive I apply a JQuery function to my select with the library Select2, that's why I need it. Thank you for your comment anyway

Comment: @ValentinV Here's the angular version for Select2, use this instead: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select